# ImageIO writes teal where black expected

Tags: java, image

I wrote the following simple code to write what should be a small, all black image to disk:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageWriteTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        final int PIXEL = 0xFF_00_00_00; // Black
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
                img.setRGB(i, j, PIXEL);
            }
         }

         ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("/tmp/testImage.jpg"));

         int sample = img.getRGB(0,0);
         System.out.println((sample & 0x00_00_00_FF) + "\t" 
             + ((sample & 0x00_00_FF_00) >>> 8) + "\t" 
             + ((sample & 0x00_FF_00_00) >>> 16) + "\t"
             + ((sample & 0xFF_00_00_00) >>> 24));

         Color color = new Color(sample, true);
         System.out.println(color.getGreen() 
             + "\t" + color.getBlue() 
             + "\t" + color.getRed() 
             + "\t" + color.getAlpha());
    }
}
```

The output to the terminal is two lines

```
0    0    0   255
0    0    0   255
```

as I expect.

The image file, however, appears to be a small teal square instead of a small black square, as shown.

[image: Output image from program]

That was run on Windows 10 and Java version 1.8.0_92, Java HotSpot.  I saw similar results earlier on a Linux machine.

I found two questions that seem somewhat related, but in both of these cases the issue seems to be that a file was read into the program from external source and had extra meta data and/or missing headers.  In this case, I created the image programmatically, so I'm expecting it to work.

- [JPEG image with wrong colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340569/jpeg-image-with-wrong-colors#comment21166430_9395544)
- [Get color of each pixel of an image using BufferedImages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391353/get-color-of-each-pixel-of-an-image-using-bufferedimages)

If I change `PIXEL = 0x00_00_00_00;` then I do get a black square. That's no doubt a clue, but one that I haven't understood yet.  What have I done wrong?  How do I fix it?

Comment: @K_7 I liked to that possible duplicate in my original post and explained why my question is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert but this is due to `JPG` not supporting alpha channels. Change the same result to `PNG` and it will be as you expected. To do that, simply use

```
ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);
```

After some searching, looks like bug in `ImageIO`
[jpeg image color gets drastically changed after just ImageIO.read() and ImageIO.write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072312/jpeg-image-color-gets-drastically-changed-after-just-imageio-read-and-imageio)

Or maybe not bug after all? Take look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39478986/1527544
Comment says, that `ARGB` for `JPG` is read as CMYK.

Comment: I tried both PNG and GIF while I was waiting for an answer and found that both work properly with respect to color - although create much larger files in the real application. The question that you linked, however, seems to point to a bug in `read` rather than `write`.  I'm doing no `read`, although it does seem likely that they are somehow related.

Comment: @Brick check the edit - looks like it is simply theated as CMYK not RGB values if you save to `jpg` files .

Comment: Yeah, the comment there actually says: `//pitfall: in a jpeg file 4 channels will be interpreted as CMYK... this is no good` and that's still on a `write` rather than a `read`. Comments on the other answer indicate that it is a bug in Java.  It must be symmetrically wrong between read and write though, so I'm guess I'm stuck.. It is handy to know that it's treating it at CMYK - even if that's not what it's supposed to do! (Documented behavior is for the API to do color model conversion behind the scenes as far as I can tell.)

Comment: @Brick and maybe there is the actuall bug.